# Is the prime $p$ bigger than $k$ if $\frac{n}{2k}$ is smaller than $p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n \geq 2k^2$ (I am not sure that this condition is necessary). Let $p$ be the largest prime such that $p \leq \dfrac{n}{k}$. By the [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) we have that $\dfrac{n}{2k} \leq p \leq \dfrac{n}{k}$ (to be strict we can write $\Big \lceil \dfrac{n}{2k} \Big \rceil \leq p \leq \Big \lfloor\dfrac{n}{k} \Big \rfloor$).

My question is that if from this facts it is possible to say that $k \leq p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ p\ge\frac n{2k}\ge\frac{2k^2}{2k}=k$$

Comment: What an stupid... Thanks.